# Obtain cycles with $a < $ nr. of edges $< b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a chemistry/mathematical problem and I would like to get your opinion.

Imagine you are generating a planar, cyclic molecule, with a total $N$ is the number of atoms. By Euler graph theory, the molecule has to obey to the relation:
$$
l = a - N + 1  \tag{1}
$$
Where $l$ is the total number of cycles, $a$ the number of attachments or edges and $N$ the total number of atoms or vertices.

With this formula, with $N = 10$, one can make, among others, two fused hexagons (see molecule naphthalene) which have $l = 2$ and $a = 11$ or a single ring with 10 vertices: $l = 1, a = 10, N = 10$.

As well, with $N = 12$, one can have two connected hexagons (see molecule biphenyl), but one could have a single ring, or other arrangements, turning equation $(1)$ valid.

What I would like to have, is an expression that could only generate cyclic molecules where no cycle could have more than $b$ edges and less than $a$ edges. For example, I just wanted cyclic molecules, where each cycle would have a min. of $5$ elements (pentagons) and a max. of $6$ elements (hexagons).

These polygons can be fused (like naphthalene) or connected (like biphenyl).

Thank you